# Parameter type ISO Date Format?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define a parameters type to a date time format like:

```
setDate(date: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ") {
  this.date = date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible so far.

There is however a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21044) for regex validated types, which would allow exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

The longer answer is, TypeScript doesn't do string matching. At all.

There are string literals in TypeScript:

```
type sex = 'male' | 'female';
```

Meaning that, only the specific (Literal) strings are allowed. You are asking string matching.

Comment: Yes right. I was afraid of that. What I am looking for is actually regular expression matching for parameter types. Are there useful alternatives to pass in dates in a specific format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Template literal types
(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to approach an ISO Date String type, like this:

```js
type IsoDateString = `${number}-${number}-${number}T${number}:${number}:${number}.${number}Z`;
```

The problem is, the type isn't very restrictive at all. You can also define dates with, for example, the day 100...

Anyway, it seems you can't make that type more restrictive, because if you try to do something like this:

```js
type Nums1To9 = '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9';
type Nums0To9 = '0' | Nums1To9;

type Years = `19${Nums0To9}${Nums0To9}` | `20${Nums0To9}${Nums0To9}`;
type Months = `0${Nums1To9}` | '10' | '11' | '12';
type Days = `0${Nums1To9}` | `2${Nums0To9}` | '30' | '31';
type Hours = `${'0' | '1'}${Nums0To9}` | `2${'0' | '1' | '2' | '3'}`;
type MinsSecs = `${'0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5'}${Nums0To9}`;
type MiliSecs = `${Nums0To9}${Nums0To9}${Nums0To9}`;

// This doesn't work =(
type IsoDateString = `${Years}-${Months}-${Days}T${Hours}:${MinsSecs}:${MinsSecs}.${MiliSecs}Z`;
const date: IsoDateString = '2022-10-06T11:00:00.000Z';
```

It says:

```
Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.
```

Anyway, the first approach is better than nothing!